# Using parameter of earlier call in recursive call without sending as parameter - PHP

Tags: php, recursion

Is there any way to use a variable of a method, after a recursive call (without sending that as a parameter).

For example:

```
class Doc {

    public function readDoc($file, $recursion = false) {
        if ($recursion != false) {
            // DO SOMETHING;
        }
        $filename = $file."Some added text";
        $this->readDoc($filename, 1);
    }
}
```

Here, is it possible to use the value of `$file` sent in the first call (when the `readDoc()` function is called recursively).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple stack with an array, e.g.

```
  class Doc {
    private $stack = [];

    public function readDoc($file, $recursion=false) {
          if($recursion != false)    
              DO SOMETHING

          $this->stack[] = $file;    
          $filename = $file."Some added text";
          $this->readDoc($filename, 1);
    }
}
```

And then get the first index of the array as your $file variable.

Answer (score 0):

you could also use an anonymous function to work in a different scope something like this:

```
public function test($file, $recursion = false)
{
    $rec = function($r) use ($file, &$rec)
    {
        if($r !== false) {

        }

        $filename = $file.'test';
        return $rec($r);
    };

    return $rec($recursion);
}
```

in this case the $file variable always stays the same
(be aware that the above example creates an infinite-loop)